# What is the equivalent in CSS: add content to an element is `content: "text to add";` as remove content from an element is `?????`

Tags: javascript, css, mediawiki

There is a custom namespace named `Item:` on the main wiki that I edit, and the complaint is that every page inside that namespace shows up as `Item:This_item` -- `Item:That_item` -- `Item:Foo_item`.

I went surfing through the web and the CSS for that skin, and came across:

```css
span#ca-nstab-main:before,
span#ca-nstab-user:before,
span#ca-nstab-wp:before {
content: "[ ";
}
span#ca-talk:before {
content: "& ";
}
span#ca-talk:after {
content: " ]";
}
```

which takes the namespace name "I'll use `main` as the example" and the corresponding `talk` page name and makes them show up as `[ main & talk ]` instead of `main talk`.

I was wondering if there was something similar that would allow me to display `Item:Foo` as just `Foo` stripping the "`Item:`" off.  I know that the items listed on the category page are in `div#mw-pages` `a` tags.

Perhaps even an in-line way to use JavaScript to strip the first five characters off?  I say "in-line" because [$wgAllowUserJs](http://mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAllowUserJs) is set to  false on this wiki.

Edit:
The wiki-core parses it out as:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/      
a[title^=&quot;Item:&quot;] {
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Geneva, Arial, Verdana, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -2.1em;
}
/*]]>*/       
</style>
```

How do I make the quotes not be parsed, is there a trick?  Can I use single quotes instead of double like on the font-family line?

Comment: Ouch! Please indent your code and divide your question into paragraphs. Otherwise, people might not answer your question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this if you're only able to use CSS. (http://jsfiddle.net/zPJHU/)

```
li a {
/* monospace fonts may be more consistant cross browsers */
font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
font-size: 1em;
display:inline-block;
overflow:hidden;
text-indent: -2.9em; /* may have to play with this value */
}
li a:hover{
    font-size: 1.8em; /* just for demonstration of font-size increase */
}
```

Demo markup:

```
<p>Hover over links to increase font-size</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#Item:wicket" title="This really says: 'Item:Wicket'">Item:Wicket</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Item:chewbacca" title="This really says: 'Item:Chewbacca'">Item:Chewbacca</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Item:obiwan" title="This really says: 'Item:Obi Wan Kenobi'">Item:Obi Wan Kenobi</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like it; is there a way for it to test and only apply the text-indent if the name starts with `Item:`?

Comment: You can target the "title" attribute like so: a[title^="Item:"]. Updated fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zPJHU/1/

Comment: The answer to my edit in OP is yes.  Thank you sooo much..  This is great!

Answer (score 0):

dunno if that works, but you could prepand and append a span open / close tag at the right position to have the following:

```
<span class="hideme">Foo:</span>Bar
```

as i've said i haven't tried it, but i don't know another way and there might be no possibility to cut content by just using css. javascript should do it.

Comment: The actual html on the page shows up as: `<a href="/page/Item:Foo_bar" title="Item:Foo bar">Item:Foo bar</a>`.  So, how would your suggestion work?  I just want to change it to `<a href="/page/Item:Foo_bar" title="Foo bar">Foo bar</a>` (strip "Item:" from title & innerHTML).

Comment: changing the title attribute may not work using css. the a href may be access via javascript if it contains an id.

Comment: It is parsed out by the wiki-core exactly as I have typed above.. No name or id attribute.